# Kotlin configurando font dentro do fragment

Tags: android-fragment, kotlin, font

Lá estou com uma dúvida, como eu faço para, modificar a fonte de dentro de um fragment?

```
tvAgradecimento.setText("Teste")
        tvAgradecimento.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(tvAgradecimento.context.assets, "dinpro_medium.ttf"))
```

ERRO

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at br.com.adrianofpinheiro.testesantander.fragment.ContatoEnviadoFragment.onCreateView(ContatoEnviadoFragment.kt:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

A exceção `NullPointerException` está tentando dizer que o `TextView` é nulo. Isso pode acontecer quando o parâmetro do ID usado quando você declarou a variável usando `findViewById` não é igual ao ID do `TextView` declarado no XML. Verifique se os dois possuem o mesmo ID.

Caso não seja, você disse que o texto está dentro de um Fragmento, então você pode estar fazendo a declaração da `TextView` dentro da Activity, e não no Fragmento. Quando você declara

```
tvAgradecimento = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.idTextView)
```

ele subentende que o `TextView` pertence à Activity. Quando você declara

```
tvAgradecimento = idFragmento.findViewById<TextView>(R.idTextView)
```

ele informa que o `TextView` pertence ao Fragmento. Tente fazer essa alteração.